# Wrong amount outputting

Tags: java, math

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AddCoins {

    /**
     * Nick Jones
     * 2/5/2015
     * Ad Coins
     */
        public static String getDollarAmount(double pen, double nic, double dim, double qua) {
        double total;
        String amount;

        pen = pen%1;
        nic = nic%5;
        dim = dim%10;
        qua = qua%25;

        total = pen + nic + dim + qua;
        amount = ("$" + total);

        return amount;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        double pen;
        double nic;
        double dim;
        double qua;
        String amount;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("enter amount of pennies:  ");
        pen = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("enter amount of nickles:  ");
        nic = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("enter amount of dimes:  ");
        dim = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("enter amount of quarters:  ");
        qua = input.nextInt();

        amount = getDollarAmount(pen, nic, dim, qua);

        System.out.println(amount);
    }

}
```

This program is suppose to take all inputted amount of change in the main statment then transfer it to the getDollerAmount(); so then all the change is converted to their values then totaled up and set to String amount so i can return amount back to the main program and output it. but the math isnt right and wont give me the output.

for example

enter amount of pennies:
1
enter amount of nickles:
1
enter amount of dimes:
1
enter amount of quarters:
1
$3.0

this should be $0.41 but it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your `getDollarAmount` method you have the following lines:

```
pen = pen%1;
nic = nic%5;
dim = dim%10;
qua = qua%25;
```

The `%` symbol is called `Modulus` and actually is not what you are looking for.  It actually is taking the remainder of each variable after it has been divided by 1, 5, 10, 25.

So when you entered 1 for each coin amount it was doing:

```
1%1=0 // because 1 divided by 1 has no remainder
1%5=1
1%10=1
1%25=1

total = 0+1+1+1 =3
```

What you want is to actually get the proper value for each coin.  This is done by multiplying the amount of coins by it's value i.e `totalCoinValue = coinAmount * coinValue`

Here is what the method should look like:

```
public static String getDollarAmount(double pen, double nic, double dim, double qua) {
    double total;
    String amount;

    pen = pen * 0.01;
    nic = nic * 0.05;
    dim = dim * 0.10;
    qua = qua * 0.25;

    total = pen + nic + dim + qua;
    amount = ("$" + total);

    return amount;
}
```